# What is purpose of id attribute in Android <xliff:g> placeholder tags in string resources?

Tags: android

The Android app developer [localization checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html) recommends the use of   placeholder tags for text that shouldn't be translated. That part I understand.

It also recommends to "always add an id attribute that explains what the placeholder is for". That part I don't understand. When I look at examples from the Android open source project I see many cases where such IDs are used, for instance:

```
<string name="photo_view_count"><xliff:g id="current_pos">%d</xliff:g> of <xliff:g id="count">%d</xliff:g></string>
```

(from /frameworks/opt/photoviewer/res/values/strings.xml)

The IDs defined in that string ("current_pos" and "count") are not referenced anywhere in the underlying Java code, however, so what is the purpose? Is it purely a help to translators, supposed to explain what the placeholder value can be?

I could see a purpose in identifying each of the placeholders with an ID if those IDs were in fact referenced in the code, since that would serve the purpose of allowing the translator to switch the order of the placeholders around. But that is not happening. And the IDs in question are even uppercased in the translated versions ("CURRENT_POS" and "COUNT") - a function of the translation tool used in this case, I think.

Comment: I believe the ID attribute is just text that is intended to indicate what the placeholder is for to the translator. As you noted from the docs: "When you declare a placeholder tag, always add an id attribute that explains what the placeholder is for." These won't be found in code, they are just an "explanation." I think ID is a confusing name for this, but it is what it is.

Comment: The spec for XLIFF 1.2 (which is what the Android files use in their namespacing of XLIFF) defines the "g" tag, Generic Group Placeholder, and the attributes: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#g -- There it seems the "id" has a little more solid definition, but it's actual value is "determined by the tool creating the document." I would *guess* that  outside of Android most tools use that field a little more rigidly, and Android is overloading it to say "just use it to explain."